# Asp.net PopupControlExtender inside UpdatePanel

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, popupcontrolextender

So I use `PopupControlExtender` (to edit some of the fields) inside `ListViewControl` which itself is embedded inside an `UpdatePanel`.

The problem is as follows whenever you cause `partail` `postback` the popup panels are created client side outside the `updatepanel`. And you get more clientside controls with the same clientside ID. When you postback with popup panel the server side control eg. Texbox has `Text` = `clientsidecontrol1.text`, `clientsidecontrol2.text`, `clientsidecontrol.text3`

Is there a way to prevent this.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Test.aspx.cs" Inherits="Secure_Test" %>

<%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="cc1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <div>

        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="InputLabel" runat="server" Text="Whatever you put in the textbox"></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:Label runat="server"> <%= DateTime.Now.ToString() %></asp:Label>
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Refresh" />
            <br />
            <asp:LinkButton ID="PopupLB" runat="server">Popup</asp:LinkButton>
            <br />

            <cc1:PopupControlExtender ID="PopupControlExtender1" runat="server" PopupControlID="Panel1" TargetControlID="PopupLB" CommitProperty="Value">
            </cc1:PopupControlExtender>

            <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="InputTB" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Button ID="SubmitBTN" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
                            onclick="SubmitBTN_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
                     </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </asp:Panel>

        </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using AjaxControlToolkit;

public partial class Secure_Test : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void SubmitBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        PopupControlExtender pce = AjaxControlToolkit.PopupControlExtender.GetProxyForCurrentPopup(Page);
        pce.Commit("Popup");
        InputLabel.Text = InputTB.Text;
    }
}
```

To make it easier to test i post the code of an example page I used for testing.

To make myself clear here is an example:

I click `Popup`. Type "asdf" in the textbox and click Submit.

`InputPanel` displays "asdf"

I click `Popup` again. Type "qwerty" in the textbox and click Submit.

InputPanel now displays "qwerty,asdf"

When you check it the firebug you get this:

```
<form id="form1" action="Test.aspx" method="post" name="form1">
<div>
<input type="hidden" value=";;AjaxControlToolkit, Version=3.0.30930.21526, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=28f01b0e84b6d53e:pl-PL:c83bc095-c5d9-40da-b175-dc46338fcc3a:865923e8:91bd373d:596d588c:411fea1c:e7c87f07:bbfda34c:30a78ec5:42b7c466;" id="ToolkitScriptManager1_HiddenField" name="ToolkitScriptManager1_HiddenField">



</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//&lt;![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['form1'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.form1;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]&gt;
</script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="/WebResource.axd?d=B2RAZw_YugtketKJqWIbXA2&amp;t=634051184591131846"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=zifZiisoqXYJSwLXuAZ4DmtrWVvn9x0W1r7qfDo40UU7q9QYoa5ChdBZD6dDL66f0flKVDmPL2woIPesut_FUpsFZUN2A5sDN7IOqPUOZO41&amp;t=1a45d080"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//&lt;![CDATA[
if (typeof(Sys) === 'undefined') throw new Error('Ładowanie struktury strony klienta ASP.NET Ajax nie powiodło się.');
//]]&gt;
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=zifZiisoqXYJSwLXuAZ4DmtrWVvn9x0W1r7qfDo40UU7q9QYoa5ChdBZD6dDL66fyxEJaYB3uJEQ0r_TmOPczeBZ1gpFH5a6x4ug130lptsKAcGA3S1vt08sHQo5sFtH0&amp;t=1a45d080"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Secure/Test.aspx?_TSM_HiddenField_=ToolkitScriptManager1_HiddenField&amp;_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bAjaxControlToolkit%2c+Version%3d3.0.30930.21526%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d28f01b0e84b6d53e%3apl-PL%3ac83bc095-c5d9-40da-b175-dc46338fcc3a%3a865923e8%3a91bd373d%3a596d588c%3a411fea1c%3ae7c87f07%3abbfda34c%3a30a78ec5%3a42b7c466"></script>
<div>


</div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
//&lt;![CDATA[
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._initialize('ToolkitScriptManager1', document.getElementById('form1'));
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance()._updateControls(['tUpdatePanel1','tUpdatePanel2'], [], [], 90);
//]]&gt;
</script>

    <div>

        <div id="UpdatePanel1">
            <span id="InputLabel">qwerty,asdf</span>
            <br>
            <span>2010-06-15 18:26:50</span>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" id="Button1" value="Refresh" name="Button1">
            <br>
            <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('PopupLB','')" id="PopupLB">Popup</a>
            <br>





        </div>

    </div>


<script type="text/javascript">
//&lt;![CDATA[
(function() {var fn = function() {$get('ToolkitScriptManager1_HiddenField').value = '';Sys.Application.remove_init(fn);};Sys.Application.add_init(fn);})();Sys.Application.initialize();
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(AjaxControlToolkit.PopupControlBehavior, {"CommitProperty":"Value","PopupControlID":"Panel1","dynamicServicePath":"/Secure/Test.aspx","id":"PopupControlExtender1"}, null, null, $get("PopupLB"));
});
//]]&gt;
</script>
<div id="Panel1" style="position: absolute; left: 8px; top: 73px; z-index: 1000; display: none; visibility: hidden;">

                <div id="UpdatePanel2">

                        <input type="text" id="InputTB" name="InputTB">
                        <input type="button" id="SubmitBTN" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('SubmitBTN','')" value="Submit" name="SubmitBTN">

  </div>

 </div><span style="display: none ! important;"><input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value=""></span><span style="display: none ! important;"><input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value=""></span><span style="display: none ! important;"><input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUJMTkwNzc2NzAzD2QWAgIDD2QWAgIDD2QWAmYPZBYCAgEPDxYCHgRUZXh0BQtxd2VydHksYXNkZmRkZApLPc2nZUC+UkZsCrByuofHMah5"></span><span style="display: none ! important;"><input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWBQLi2qWdAwKM54rGBgKIkJujDQKbjp+pDQKc7v+tArliNtJzeG8HrfsGBBXIViJAUGMz"></span><div id="Panel1" style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute; left: 8px; top: 73px; z-index: 1000; display: none;">

                <div id="UpdatePanel2">

                        <input type="text" id="InputTB" value="asdf" name="InputTB">
                        <input type="button" id="SubmitBTN" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('SubmitBTN','')" value="Submit" name="SubmitBTN">

 </div>

</div><div id="Panel1" style="display: none; visibility: hidden; position: absolute;">

                <div id="UpdatePanel2">

                        <input type="text" id="InputTB" value="qwerty,asdf" name="InputTB">
                        <input type="button" id="SubmitBTN" onclick="javascript:__doPostBack('SubmitBTN','')" value="Submit" name="SubmitBTN">

 </div>

</div></form>
```

`InputTB` and `Panel1` where generated 3 time.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using newer version of the AjaxControlToolkit. It solves the problem mentioned above and added couple others ;) Anyways i still recomend it.

Answer (score 0):

The script will be invoked automatically after Postback

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad() {
        var panelRef = $get("<%=Panel1.ClientID%>");

        panelRef.style.left = YOUR_VALUE;
        panelRef.style.top = "58px";
    }
</script>
```

Course there is possible to make it dynamic recalling the position of another control for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function pageLoad() {
        var panelRef = $get("<%=Panel1.ClientID%>");
        var div = $get("<%=Button1.ClientID%>"); 

        panelRef.style.left = div.style.left;
        panelRef.style.top = "58px";
    }
</script>
```